# Animating a mask for png image in Android

Tags: java, android, png, android-canvas, mask

So I am trying to develop an animation that fills a png into white like this:

[image]

For the transparent woman, I have a custom view that draws the png, and an AsyncTask for the animation that calls the view's invalidate() method.

I was able to draw and animate almost everything, but I cannot find a solution for filling the png from bottom to top. How can I create a "mask" that draws exactly the shape of the woman in white from bottom to top?

Comment: y dont u overlap multiple pngs.... make a virtual look

Comment: post at least two/three images how it would look like